# SSRS: Dynamic difference between two columns in MATRIX

Tags: reporting-services

I try to create (in SSRS) a summary of incomes in years and I'm stuck when I try to compare them.

e.g. of my table, where Rok = Years:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rjyza.png]

I have table like at image above where A and B are Expressions (sums of incomes). Columns are years from the SQL query, So 2020 will appear soon. I would like to divide 2019 vs 2018 but dynamically so if 2020 will appear, everything will calculate between 2020 and 2019. Do you know any solution for that ? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to have an individual filtered column group for each year.
Second add in column outside group right, labelled as compare and
Insert the following expression: =ReportItems!Rok.value - ReportItems!Rok1.value ( Rok and Rok1 are the Name available from Text Box Properties for each filtered column group)

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply. What do you mean by "individual filtered column group for each year" ? I have a SQL query with a lot of data and i just have added column year (rok) for this query. Should I type here manually: 2019, 2018, 2017 etc ? it won't be dynamically, and every year on january i will be forced to add next year :(

Comment: @csc1 please look at my profile at send me a copy of your .rdl file and will post some more information

Comment: click on the first Rok column, rm click, column group then group properties, select filters and add,  in drop down box expression select Rok,operator = and then type in '2019', press ok. then add another column group and modify filter to be equal to 2018,

Comment: Hi,i did it like you said and nothing appeared. I cant insert screenshot in comment. But column is just empty (without name and data)

Comment: But... I did similar thing, i just have created few groups (as many as i have Rok Values) and I have add filters as you said, and now it works. Thanks for help :) !