# SSRS Matrix show difference between dynamic column groups

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

==Edit in relation to answers==

Both answers provided give the required result just in separate ways.

@Hannover_Fist's answer displays better but is a little more rigid in its design, it currently works fine for a Saturday to Saturday report, but would need a edit per report if the recurring date span changed

@niktrs answer doesn't display as cleanly, even with a very very small top row, but has a bit more flexibility and does show the latest column compared to the latest minus 1 column with a little more flexability

==Edit in relation to answers==

I have an SSRS matrix that dynamically pulls from a database a list of values. The matrix represents each value as a row with a date stamp period as a different column.
The DB table is populated by a stored procedure that runs a number of queries and snapshots this into a static table, on a weekly basis.

The report shows for each line the sum of records for each date stamp, and is ordered so the latest date stamp shows as the most current record. i.e.

| Report | 03/04/21 | 27/03/21 | 20/03/2021 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Report1 | 1000 | 990 | 800 |
| Report2 | 100 | 2000 | 2500 |

I'm wanting to add in a calculated column that appears to the left of the matrix element that shows the difference between the latest datestamp and the latest (minus 1) datestamp as below:

| Report | Change | 03/04/21 | 27/03/21 | 20/03/2021 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Report1 | +10 | 1000 | 990 | 800 |
| Report2 | -1900 | 100 | 2000 | 2500 |

This date stamp column would dynamically change each week, so would be comparing different columns every 7 days i.e.

Week 1 would be 03/04/2021 compared with 27/03/2021

Week 2 would be 10/04/2021 compared with 03/04/2021

Week 3 would be 17/04/2021 compared with 10/04/2021

I've looked at the following options, but these either allow me to look at the first and last column of the matrix, or presume that the groupings are static/remain static for a longer period of time that the 7 days that mine do.

[how to subtract adjacent columns in an ssrs matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20247585/how-to-subtract-adjacent-columns-in-an-ssrs-matrix)

[find the difference between two columns in an ssrs matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20148560/find-the-difference-between-two-columns-in-an-ssrs-matrix)

[SSRS: Dynamic difference between two columns in MATRIX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59786645/ssrs-dynamic-difference-between-two-columns-in-matrix)

I've not been able to find a solution that meets the requirement of comparing dynamic column groups, that change on a regular basis

Comment: This is fairly common question that never gets a satisfactory answer. If I needed to do this I would do it in the dataset query. If you show a sample of your current dataset output then that would be useful (does it have a week number for instance?)

Comment: Depending the query and the calculations, sometimes doing it on the database instead of the SSRS would create unnecessary overhead. On the otherhand, there are simple calculations that are hard to do directly on SSRS

Comment: I can show you that my answer displays well with minimal margins. I left the upper row large to give you better understanding of my solution. I have also make the borders for the first row to look like one with the second. If you have a date parameter using expressions like Hannover did is much simpler but if you don't, you need workarounds to overcome SSRS limitations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use custom code to get the values and the difference of the first two columns.

I have created 2 functions:

SetVariance takes as parameter the field value. Internally it counts column number and store the first two values in the related variable.

GetVariance returns the value and resets the variables

```
Public Dim column_num As Integer 
Public Dim value1 As Integer
Public Dim value2 As Integer

Public Function SetVariance (v As Integer)

  column_num = column_num + 1
  If column_num = 1 Then value1 = v
  If column_num = 2 Then value2 = v
 
End Function

Public Function GetVariance() As Integer
  Dim var As Integer
  var = value1 - value2
  column_num = 0
  value1 = 0
  value2 = 0
  Return var
End Function
```

In order to make SetVariance work, you have to add one line before the group values (orange) and call use the function in the expression

```
=Code.SetVariance(Sum(Fields!Val.Value))
```

Set the line height as small as possible (you can't make it invisible otherwise calculation won't work)

For the change value (yellow cell) call the GetVariance function

```
Code.GetVariance()
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you don't need to use the column grouping, you can use the whole dataset for each Report and then filter for the latest week and the one before that.

If we ass**u**me that last Saturday is the last date and the week before is the one to compare to, you could use an expression like

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields.DateStamp.Value = TODAY.AddDays(0 - TODAY.DayOfWeek - 1), Fields.COUNT_FIELD.Value, 0)) - 
 SUM(IIF(Fields.DateStamp.Value = TODAY.AddDays(0 - TODAY.DayOfWeek - 8), Fields.COUNT_FIELD.Value, 0))
```

This will sum up the records' COUNT_FIELD with a DATE_STAMP of last Saturday and subtract the sum of the records' COUNT_FIELD with a DATE_STAMP of the previous Saturday.